# URL rewrite with multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to convert an URL, with some params like this (where the letters l,v and n represents input parameters).

```
/anytext/l1v5n3
```

to a an URL containing a query string:

```
/index.php?liv=1&id=5&lang=3
```

The parameters l, v, n could be in any order and the following value could be numeric and can include special symbols (+,-, etc.)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What kind of pretty URL scheme is this? Have you made any attempts to solve it yourself?

Comment: it's just a my idea. I've tried with something like: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/(\bl\b(\w+|&\w+;)+)$ with no luck :(

Comment: tried also with: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/.*l(\d+)[vlcmnbfstprio]|-|_|$